# How to set/create a Generics instance?

Tags: c#

I Have following problem:

```
class Request<T>
{
    private T sw; 

    public Request()
    {
        //How can i create here the instance like
        sw = new T();
    }

}
```

is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) constraint:

```
class Request<T> where T : new() {
    private T sw; 

    public void Request() {
        sw = new T();
    }
}
```

This tells the compiler that `T` will always have an accessible parameterless constructor (no, you can't specify any other kind of constructor).

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare the constraint `where T : new()` in the class declaration. This is restricting `T` to types with a public default constructor. For example:

```
class Request<T> where T : new() 
{
    private T sw; 

    public Request()
    {
        sw = new T();
    }
 }
```

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Thank you, an example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell the compiler that T always implements a parameterless constructor.

```
class Request<T> where T : new()
```

Comment: @BoltClock: a parameterless constructor perhaps? nullary constructor? what's the best word here?